# Regex: how to limit .* to only numbers & punctuation

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to create statements where I can use `.*` with conditions (no consequtive two letters for example), and I've been failing for a while. Starting here:

```
"SOMETEXT 1-7, 39-41, 12B, 1-7, SOME OTHER TEXT, SOME MORE OTHER TEXT"
```

I want to find:

```
"SOMETEXT 1-7, 39-41, 12B, 1-7,"
```

I've made it to the point where I can look for text followed by a number and any comma:

```
^[A-Z]+[A-Z] [1-9].*,
```

using the regular expression builder here:
https://regex101.com/r/yK6oF4/1

but here I still get:

```
"SOMETEXT 1-7, 39-41, 12B, 1-7, SOME OTHER TEXT,"
```

how can I tell .* to stop when it finds two consequtive letters? Or a comma, a space, and a letter? Any condition like that. I want to look only for numbers (including "numbers" such as 12B) and punctuations after what I've found before the `.*`.

I use R but I think this question is general about regular expressions.

Comment: Try this: `^[A-Z]+[A-Z] .*[1-9],`

Comment: Regex questions should always be tagged with the appropriate language, as regex is implemented differently across languages/libraries.

Comment: @anubhava thanks! That works in this case but I still accepted the answer below because it is a bit more general (eg if for some data reason there is a space between the number and the comma, it still works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^[A-Z]+[A-Z] [1-9].*?(?=,\s*[A-Z]{2})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mnhNmA/2). You can use it as `stringr::str_extract(x, "^[A-Z]+[A-Z] [1-9].*?(?=,\\s*[A-Z]{2})")`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z]+[A-Z]` - two or more uppercase letters (= `[A-Z]{2,}`)
- `[1-9]` - a digit from `1` to `9`
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=,\s*[A-Z]{2})` - a positive lookahead that requires `,`, zero or more whitespaces and then two uppercase ASCII letters immediately to the right of the current location.

In *base* R though, you can use

```r
sub("^([A-Z]+[A-Z] [1-9].*?),\\s*[A-Z]{2}.*", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mnhNmA/3).

Comment: fantastic, thanks as well for the Details, that helps a lot!

Comment: just for completeness, there is no way to go the other way around and instead of looking for the two letters, restrict .* to only look for numbers and punctuation, right?

Comment: @Jakob Replace `.*` with `[\p{N}\p{P}\p{S}]*` or `[[:punct:][:digit:]]*`